# Intellij Idea prompt on hover

Tags: intellij-idea, prompt, popupwindow, mousehover

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 and cannot find any tool for show popup window or prompt when hovering over a button. Which setting should be turned on/off for this?

[image]

For example i wish to see what does button with wrench mean on hover it

Comment: Which button and what popup or prompt do you expect to see? Show it on the screenshot.

Comment: @Andrey something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | **Support screen readers** option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your problem, but under `File`, `Settings`, `Editor`, `Code Editing` you may find what you are looking for. There is a checkbox there to show quick documentation on hover.

Comment: Nope, that's another feature, I't doesn't affect the button prompt

Comment: Now I think I understand. Check if you have the "Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance, Accessibility > Support screen readers" option enabled. If so, try to disable it and then restart IntelliJ.